# addCookie method throws 'addCookie called with non-cookie parameter'

Tags: cookies, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am struggling with this error message which has no direct forum discussion anywhere. From some of the things I saw around the web I tried:

- Changing localhost to 127.0.0.1
- Played around with `browser.driver.manage()` v/s `browser.manage()`
- Cleaning out/updating my node modules

The same code runs on other machines with same configuration (Win 10, chromedriver 2 etc.)

The code essetially gets the cookie value through API calls before

and uses it as such:

`browser.get(URL);
browser.manage().addCookie('cookie_name', value);`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assumption that you are on Protractor 5.0.0. Adding cookies have been changed in selenium webdriver 3 and was noted as a breaking change in the [Protractor changelog](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

Before:

```
browser.manage().addCookie('testcookie', 'Jane-1234');
```

After:

```
browser.manage().addCookie({name:'testcookie', value: 'Jane-1234'});
```

Comment: I am still on Protractor 4 but this worked! thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks after so much googling and digging through old half baked answers I finally got the answer I needed. A Hash!

Answer (score 4):

The answer above did not work for me because i kept getting this error:
"Expected 2-6 arguments but got 1"

This is what I had to do to make it compile at least:

```
(browser.manage() as any).addCookie({name:'cookieName', value: 'cookieVal'});
```

Here is the thread I got this info from:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4148

It is still an open issue.